# Creating a timer counter

Tags: java

I would like to create a time counter (count seconds/miliseconds or what ever) that will return the amount of time counted what I want to. I don't want to preform any kind of task using this counter, I just want to know the amount of time counted.

Is it possible?how?

Comment: I said like that because, your question shows no effort.

Comment: @ImriPersiado : -1 behave urself, give some respect.

Comment: You know exatcly to what kind of answer I'm looking for, if you don't have anything usefull to say then don't.

Comment: I give respect, his comment is unrespectfull.

Comment: by "return the amount of time counted what I want to", do you mean that you want to count down from (lets just say 10) to 0, like 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0? If so then I have code that I can share with you

Comment: well he can, he is not the one who is asking question or help

Comment: @ImriPersiado here people respect everyone, but one tip is if you want to get good answers you need to first post good question

Comment: Totally agree with you but he could avoid posting this comment, anyway I got my answer let's not make a big deal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
long t0 = System.nanoTime();
// do something
long t1 = System.nanoTime();
long elapsedNanoseconds = t1 - t0;
```

Guava has a [Stopwatch class](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html) encapsulating this.

EDIT:

If what you need is a scheduler, then use a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Comment: I don't want to be limited by variables.

Comment: If I want to do something every 10 minutes that impossible by your answer.

Comment: So in fact, you want a scheduler? Why do you say in your question: "I don't want to preform any kind of task using this counter, I just want to know the amount of time counted", since it seems now that you **do** want to do something using this "counter"? See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Comment: @ImriPersiado, in the question, you said you didn't want to perform a task. So do you, or do you not? You should use executor service if you need scheduled tasks

Comment: Sorry. I've choosen the wrong words. I will make a task every x time but not through this class.